# Importing a resource file

Tags: python, resources, pyqt

I'm having trouble removing a resource file in a pyqt document, I'm also using monkeystudio IDE. I madea  program with images and all linked to a resource file called "resources.qyc" and now I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from Login import Login
  File "J:\Newone\Login.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mainwindow
  File "J:\Newone\mainwindow.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Addcadet
  File "J:\Newone\Addcadet.py", line 6, in <module>
    ( Ui_Addcadet, QDialog ) = uic.loadUiType( 'Addcadet.ui' )
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 203, in loadUiType
    exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
  File "<string>", line 179, in <module>
ImportError: No module named resources_rc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first have to compile the resource file using [`pyrcc4`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/resources.html). You'll run something like this from command line:

```
pyrcc4 ResourceFile.qrc -o ui_ResourceFile.py
```

Comment: @user2219834 You execute it from your shell, `ResourceFile.qrc` is the name of the input file and `ui_ResourceFile.py` the name of the output file. When you import the resources you'll use the last one, somthing like `import ui_ResourceFile`. ps: Perhaps it's a typo, but the proper extension for resource files is `.qrc`

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid, but you can't simply type it into the shell? and which shell?

Comment: That depends on your OS. If it is Windows that you are using `cmd.exe`, otherwise it's probably `bash`